# What is the most ideal way to add validation to Spring REST Service Request Parameters

Tags: spring, rest, validation

I have a Spring-REST service that has support for GET, POST, PUT requests and they all have been mapped in a `@Controller` (Sorry for stating the obvious, just new to the technology)

Now each method (RequestMapping) has its own parameters like one takes in id
other takes in name and third one takes in secretKey

I want to validate these request parameters in my own custom manner

Now tried looking up as many tutorials online as possible but did not come across any solution that would best serve my situation.

Here is what I mean: 
I saw a tutorial for POST request parametes by using `@RequestParam` or `@Valid` but that does not work for GET requests (That's what I read)

I saw most people recommending JS303 but that does not suit my need as I need to validate the secretKey against the DB (id and name may be I can use JSR @Size but even the id and name would need further validation)

I also saw some recommending `@Validator` but that would mean I will need a validator class for each and and every parameter like `IdValidator`, `NameValidator` etc

Here is something that I am hoping to accomplish: 
One `Validator` (Can be either something that implements Validator or COnstraintValidator) however its implementation should cater to validation of all kinds of requests (can definitely have multiple methods inside it based on what request its validating) and should throw a `CustomException` that I created

I am not posting what I have tried because it is actually too much code that I just copy pasted from what I searched online. If you want I can post the links that I copied the code from.

P.S. I am not an expert on Spring, but trying to learn

Comment: Is there a specific reason that using a filter would not work for you in this case? I am talking about adding a filter to your application which can act as a validation layer. Here is an example for reference: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/How_to_add_validation_logic_to_HttpServletRequest

Comment: One validator to rule them all is quite a bad idea... You don't want to create that kind of god object. Also validation works regardless of what kind of request method it is. Don't use request parameters use objects, those object you can annotate with JSR303 validations and have validation. Nothing custom to write all out-of-the-box.

Comment: @M.Derium Would you be able to point me to an example.